# I need to replace the value for a running variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

Need help with this code...looking to append four records with a running variable

```
For sec_ref = 1 To 4
    qrysecscr = "v_secscr_" & sec_ref
    qrysecscr_val = Eval(qrysecscr)

    inssql1 = " Insert into sur_sec_score (Survey_ID, Section_ID, Section_Score) values "
    inssql1 = inssql1 & "(""" & v_survey_id & """, " & sec_ref & ", " & qrysecscr_val & ")"

    'CurrentDb().Execute inssql1, dbFailOnError

    MsgBox inssql1
Next
```

Comment: do you mean get the values from a field, or 4 separate variables named v_secscr_x?

Comment: 4 separate variables calculated in the form. Ex - insert 4 records with values of each v_secscr_1, v_secscr_2, v_secscr_3 and v_secscr_4

Comment: Use an array `dim arr_v_secscr(3)` then you can do.

Comment: Let me explain in detail... I have already stored 4 values in each of the variable as follows

v_secscr_1 = 2
v_secscr_2 = 4
v_secscr_3 = 5
v_secscr_4 = 1

instead of writting four insert into statements, i want the VBA code to repeat the statement four times with a for loop that will insert four records, with the value of each variable as a new record

Comment: so use an array :o)

Comment: Thanks my friend i am looking at some other alternative as this is a simple example but have a complex code to build on the same lines